# XElement.Element doesn't return a null value

Tags: c#, xml

When I run the program and I set a wrong value for `_moduleParent` the exception appears
and says 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I want to return a null string. How can I deal with this exception?

```cs
string sioModuleName = "";
string sioModuleDescription = String.Empty;
try
{
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
    xDoc = XDocument.Load(_xmlPath);
    //Root
    var sioModule = xDoc.Element(_moduleName);
    if(sioModule != null)
    {
        sioModuleName = sioModule.Element(_moduleParent).Value;//here is the problem
        sioModuleDescription = sioModule.Element("SIO-DEFINITION").Value;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Module Name");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`XContainer.Element(XName)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element?view=net-6.0) returns an `XElement` if an element with the specified name exists, otherwise it will return `null`. Your exception occurs because you are reading the `Value` property of a null reference. So you need to handle that. There are two options:

Use the built-in explicit conversions:

```cs
sioModuleName = (string)sioModule.Element(_moduleParent);
```

Use the null-conditional operator:

```cs
sioModuleName = sioModule.Element(_moduleParent)?.Value;
```